# Right click on a drop down

Tags: java, selenium

Brand new to Java, so please bear with me.  I am using Selenium, but trying to code around it.  The goal is to go here (or to a similar page) and download the four files under "APPS Results."

http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_uploads/default/df0fdd5403505bb2607ec19b915c0f81/index.html

Since when I automate getting to this site, Firefox is opened in a default mode so the setting to prompt the user (or this code) to give a path to save are disabled, I have to figure out a way to get the "save as" to appear.  I am trying to achieve this as follows:

```
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sum"));
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    for (int i=1; i <= 5; i++){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

The problem is that although I locate the first file to download, the right click occurs on the page and not the selected link.  Is there a quick fix for this, or a better way to go about it, please?

Comment: Can you get the location of the mouse and display the context menu at it's coordinates?

Comment: Is that a fixed thing? Will the mouse always be in the same place when it's automated? I've seen some examples of people messing with the placement of the mouse, but I was thinking that it only applied to someone creating a window or something.  Is that what I need to address?

Comment: If you can get the location of the "selected link" then use those coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium Webdriver doesn't support file download. You can read [this beautiful article](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/) with more details and workarounds.

Comment: Thank you very much for the website.  I got sidetracked on some other projects, so only just got back to your solution.  This is MUCH better than all the mouse clicking.  Took a little doing to convert it to my needs, but I think I have it, now.